# How to add list of names to add exiting CSV file on next row

Tags: powershell

Here I want the `$newdata` data in the next row on the same CSV file, but the result is like below:

```
NewManager
---------- 
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
```

But actually the data is:

```
NewManager
---------- 
Karthikeyan Deenadhayalan
Karthikeyan Deenadhayalan
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Karthikeyan Deenadhayalan
Karthikeyan Deenadhayalan
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
Karthikeyan Deenadhayalan
Sathiya Priya Naveen Kumar
```

My code:

```
cls
$NewData = $Olddata |
           Select @{n="NewManager";e={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties *).DisplayName}} |
           %{$_.NewManager} |
           Out-File C:\Users\Administrator.ROOTDC1\Desktop\test1.txt -Force
$import = Import-Csv $path
$print = gc C:\Users\Administrator.ROOTDC1\Desktop\test1.txt
foreach ($prints in $print) {
    #I want to add new manager list on the same file in the next row.
    foreach ($imp in $import) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $imp -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NewManager -Value $prints -Force
    }
}
$import
```

Comment: Checkout my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469972/adding-a-row-of-data-to-csv-file-via-powershell/53470146#53470146

Comment: For one thing, the value of `$NewData` is empty b/c you write the output to a file. Also, you fill the property `NewManager` with the display name of the current manager. If you want the property to show a different manager than the current one: don't put the current one into it in the first place.