# How can we add new rows at the top of the CSV file using powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell scripting and I am looking for a way to add 2 new rows at the top of the already present csv file. 
Things that I have tried is replacing the header and rows with the new rows.
I am looking for a way to add 2 new rows above the header in CSV.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code. Also when you say `Things that I have tried` we would need to know what you tried. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53470146/3099345

Comment: the easiest method is to [1] create an array of new objects that represent the new rows, [2] import the CSV file via `Import-CSV`, [3] add the 2nd to the 1st, [4] export the CSV file via `Export-CSV`.

Comment: Does the CSV file have headers? Where do the 2 new rows come from? (another CSV or strings formatted to fit the CSV or..?)

Comment: By the way, _I am looking for a way to add 2 new rows **above** the header in CSV_ wil mean you are creating an invalid CSV file. Headers (if any) need to come first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you want to add the new lines *above* the header, which means that no CSV-specific processing is needed - **it sounds like you're asking how to *prepend lines* to an existing *text file*** (which happens to contain CSV - note that *the resulting file will no longer be a valid CSV file*).

E.g., assuming a  target file named `some.csv`:

**Note**: Best to make a *backup* of the target file before trying these commands.

---

**If the input file is small enough to fit into memory as a whole**:

Reading the entire target file into memory as a single string with `Get-Content -Raw` allows for a convenient and concise solution:

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath some.csv -NoNewLine -Value (
  @'
New line 1 above header
New line 2 above header

'@ + (Get-Content -Raw some.csv)
)
```

Note that `Set-Content` applies a default character encoding (the active ANSI code page in *Windows PowerShell*, UTF-8 without BOM in PowerShell *Core*), irrespective of the current encoding of `some.csv`, so you may have to use the `-Encoding` parameter to specify the encoding explicitly.

Also note that the single-quoted here-string (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`) uses the same newline style (CRLF (Windows-style) vs. LF (Unix-style)) as the enclosing script, which may not match the style used in `some.csv` - though PowerShell itself has no problem processing files with mixed newlines styles.

---

**If the file is too large to fit into memory, use a streaming (line-by-line) approach:**

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Create a temporary file and fill it with the 2 new lines.
$tempFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
'New line 1 above header', 'New line 2 above header' | Set-Content $tempFile

# Then append the CSV file's lines one by one.
Get-Content some.csv | Add-Content $tempFile

# If that succeeded, replace the original file.
Move-Item -Force $tempFile some.csv
```

Note: Use of the `Get-Content`, `Set-Content` and `Add-Content` cmdlets is *convenient*, but *slow*; the next section shows a faster alternative.

---

**If performance matters, use .NET types such as `[IO.File]` instead:**

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Create a temporary file...
$tempFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

# ... and fill it with the 2 new lines.
$streamWriter = [IO.File]::CreateText($tempFile)
foreach ($lineToPrepend in 'New line 1 above header', 'New line 2 above header') {
  $streamWriter.WriteLine($lineToPrepend)
}

# Then append the CSV file's lines one by one.
foreach ($csvLine in [IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path some.csv))) {
  $streamWriter.WriteLine($csvLine)
}

$streamWriter.Dispose()

# If that succeeded, replace the original file.
Move-Item -Force $tempFile some.csv
```