# Copying header from one csv to another, for multiple files

Tags: powershell, csv

I am very new to any type of scripting, so don't really know how to go about this, but am wondering if there's a script to take the first row/header of a CSV, and put it at the top of a different one.

I have two different folders that look something like this,

```
newcsv1.csv
newcsv2.csv
newcsv3.csv
```

for folder one, and folder two looks like,

```
oldcsv1.csv
oldcsv2.csv
oldcsv3.csv
```

The problem is, all files in folder one have no header, and the header they should have are on the files in the old CSV folder. Is there a way to take the header row from the old CSV file, and put it at the first row of the new CSV file? All the way down the list?

The data in the `newcsv1.csv` and `oldcsv1.csv` are the same layout, just updated data. This remains true for all other files in the two folders.

Not too sure if this is clear or not, but I appreciate any and all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, the following assumes:

- that your folders contain the same number of CSV files
- and that those files are reported by `Get-ChildItem` in corresponding order; that is, the first file in the old-files folder contains the header for the first file in the new-files folder, and so on.

**Caveats**:

- The command updates the target CSV files in place; to be safe, back up the originals first.
- PowerShell never preserves an input file's character encoding; on output to a file, the respective cmdlet's default character encoding is applied; use the `-Encoding` parameter to control the output encoding, as shown below.

```sh
# Set the directory paths to the old and new files; adjust as needed.
$oldFolder = 'C:\path\to\old'
$newFolder = 'C:\path\to\new'

# Get the full file paths of the old and new CSV files.
$oldCSVs = (Get-ChildItem $oldFolder\*.csv).FullName
$newCSVs = (Get-ChildItem $newFolder\*.csv).FullName

# Loop over the file-path pairs.
foreach ($i in 0..($newCSVs.Count-1)) {
  # Extract the old CSV's header, and the new CSV's content,
  # then write them in sequence back to the new CSV file.
  # Adjust -Encoding as needed.
  Set-Content $newCSVs[$i] -NoNewline -Encoding utf8 -Value `
    ((Get-Content -TotalCount 1 $oldCSVs[$i]) + 
     [Environment]::NewLine + 
     (Get-Content -Raw $newCSVs[$i]))
}
```

- `(Get-Content -TotalCount 1 $oldCSVs[$i])` gets the header line from the old CSV.
- `(Get-Content -Raw $newCSVs[$i])` loads the content of the new CSV into memory in full, as a single, multi-line string.
- `Set-Content ... -NoNewLine ...` saves the header line followed by the new content back to the new file.

The above assumes that each new CSV file is small enough to fit into memory as a whole, which allow use of [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch, which greatly speeds up processing.

If the files are too large, a streaming PowerShell solution in the pipeline is possible, but likely too slow; see the middle section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251715/45375) for a streaming solution, and its bottom section for a fast solution using .NET APIs.

Comment: I am having an odd issue with this. I know I had previously stated that it works, but the script seems to take the header and place it NEXT to the first row, rather than on top of it. any help will be appreciated and thanked with coffee lol. For example, it will take the header, and place it in front of the first row's data, which shifts row 1 to the right and has headers to the left of that.

Comment: @eharper, my bad: I forgot that `-NoNewLine` not only suppress a _trailing_ newline, but also _between_ multiple input strings, hence your symptom. Please see my update, which now constructs a _single_ output string with an explicit newline between the header and the rest.

Comment: Dude you are awesome. You have been such a help!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @eharper; my pleasure.