# PowerShell Add values to a csv

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I would like to add values at row 1 in a csv. The first column contains dates. What i want to do is keep the date in column 1, add values in the other columns of row 1 but push the previous data in row 1 to row 2.

Current file

```
Date,Game,Team,Win,Loss
4/13/23,1,PHI,1,0
4/14/23,2,PHI,0,1
```

Would like to add new row data, 0 wins and 0 losses at index 0 keeping the date from row 0

New file:

```
Date,Game,Team,Win,Loss
4/13/23,1,PHI,0,0 <-- added 0,0
4/14/23,2,PHI,1,0 <-- moved from previous index 0
4/15/23,3,PHI,0,1 <-- moved from previous index 1
```

The only thing I was able to get to work was defaulting the values for row 1 but row 2 has the same date as row 1 instead of having row 3's date

Comment: A csv-file should have the _same_ separator between all column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a row of data to CSV file via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469972/adding-a-row-of-data-to-csv-file-via-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script works in PowerShell 3+ (as the [`\[pscustomobject\]` type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pscustomobject) was added in PowerShell 3.0) however in the same link is described how to circumvent it in version 2 using `Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty …`.

```
$csv = @'
Date,Game,Team,Win,Loss
4/13/23,1,PHI,1,0
4/14/23,2,PHI,0,1
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ','

$csvNew = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

# 1st line
[void]$csvNew.Add(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Date = $csv[0].Date
        Game = $csv[0].Game
        Team = $csv[0].Team
        Win  = '0'
        Loss = '0'
    }
)

# middle lines
for ($ii = 1; $ii -lt $csv.Count; $ii++) {
    [void]$csvNew.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Date = $csv[$ii].Date
            Game = $csv[$ii].Game
            Team = $csv[$ii].Team
            Win  = $csv[$ii-1].Win
            Loss = $csv[$ii-1].Loss
        } ) }

# last line
[void]$csvNew.Add(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Date = Get-Date -Format 'M/dd/yy' `
                -Date ([datetime]$csv[-1].Date).AddDays(1)
        Game = [int]$csv[-1].Game + 1
        Team = $csv[-1].Team
        Win  = $csv[-1].Win
        Loss = $csv[-1].Loss
    } )

$csvNew | Format-Table
```

### Output:

```
powershell -Version 3 -NoProfile -File D:\PShell\SO\76047562.ps1
```

> ```
> Date    Game Team Win Loss
> ----    ---- ---- --- ----
> 4/13/23 1    PHI  0   0
> 4/14/23 2    PHI  1   0
> 4/15/23 3    PHI  0   1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
PS D:\TEMP> type abc.csv
4/12/23 a,b,c,d
4/13/23 e,f,g,h
PS D:\TEMP> import-csv .\abc.csv -Header Date, new1, new2, new3 | export-csv abc-new.csv
PS D:\TEMP> type abc-new.csv
"Date","new1","new2","new3"
"4/12/23 a","b","c","d"
"4/13/23 e","f","g","h"
PS D:\TEMP>
```

more info: [Adding a row of data to CSV file via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469972/adding-a-row-of-data-to-csv-file-via-powershell)

Comment: And you really think I am going to edit an answer because you **CHANGED** your question ?   Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which does not have a paragraph on changing the question.